# Passing command line args to MSI from WiX bundle

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I’m on Wix 3.7. I have an MSI that I would like to set a registry key (perhaps via a Custom Action, as he will have to check if the key already exists).

I understand that a Bundle in a bootstrapper project can't change the machine state (such as setting the registry). Therefore, I'm attempting to pass a command line argument via `<MsiProperty>`, but doesn't appear to show up as a command line argument in my log file for the bootstrapper.

1. Is it possible to set a registry key up in a Bundle?
2. If not, how can I add a command line argument (or some other piece of custom data)
   to be passed to the MSI.
3. How can the MSI read whatever it is I pass to it (whether It ends up being a command line arg or something
   else).

Bundle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle 
          Name="MyInstallerBootstrapperLocalDb" 
          Version="1.0.0.0" 
          Manufacturer="some company" 
          UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="MyInstallerInstaller" 
                  SourceFile="$(var.MyInstallerInstaller.TargetPath)" 
                  Compressed="no">
        <!-- TODO - if this is being set correctly, the MSI needs to 
                    interpret it and set up the key-->
        <MsiProperty Name="SetLocalDb" Value="yes"/>
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: A property on the MSI command line needs to be a PUBLIC property. And a public property is one thats all in capitals. So, it needs to be SETLOCALDB, not SetLocalDb. And needs to be declared in the MSI as all capitals too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your MSI needs to define a property like so:

```
<Property Id="SOMEPROPERTY" Value="Default"/>
```

You can then set this property from the bundle:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="<package>.msi" Id="SomeId">
    <MsiProperty Name="SOMEPROPERTY" Value="[SomeProperty]" />
</MsiPackage>
```

After this you can set the property in the Bootstrapper as described here: [WiX Bootstrapper: How do I set burn variables from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762617/wix-bootstrapper-how-do-i-set-burn-variables-from-the-command-line)

Notice that SomeProperty is a Burn variable which you have to define:

```
<Variable Name="SomeProperty" Type="string" Value="DefaultValue" />
```

Update:

In the MSI you are then able to do a registry search based on this property:

```
<RegistrySearch Id="GetSomeValue" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\<Manufacturer>\[SOMEPROPERTY]" Name="<ValueName>" Type="raw" />
```

Comment: This works. I think the main issue is that my bundle project does a GenerateBootstrapper which actually makes it a non-wix setup.exe, and ignores anything I have defined in my bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an extra bit of information. To alter the variable values with command line, I actually had to set it as overriable.

```
<Variable Name="SomeProperty" Type="string" Value="true" bal:Overridable="yes" />
```