# How can i pass parameter to from exe file to msi?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, windows-installer

I have created an exe using bootstrapper. And now I want my installation be silent.
I can install it in silent mode using msi file with the help of following command.

```
 msiexec /i Setup.msi /qn ADDLOCAL=freature
```

but I want to install mysetup.exe in silent mode. How can I pass the parameters to msi from bootstrapper so that installation would be in silent mode.
I have goggled for hours but I couldn't figure out the way.

Comment: I didn't get your question please clear whether you want your mysetup.exe in silent mode or Setup.msi. or is it like both to be in silent mode?????

Comment: i want my mysetup.exe in silent mode.

Comment: then why are you passing parameter to msi from bootstrapper??? Is it like you want command/flag for installing it in silent mode Same as you used for your msi (/qn)??

Comment: yes i want to install my setup file in silent mode. but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: what i think you want is installer command line switches for silent install. try (command prompt)  mysetup.exe -s

Comment: i've tried that, but it raises an error "invalid parameter /s"

Comment: Its '-' and not '/'.Check out my answer for more switches

Comment: i've used -s but its shows /s

Comment: What kind of executable are you talking about? Is it a windows installer executable? Or something else?

Comment: Looks like the words in your question is also misleading. How to pass parameters from MSI to my exe? That's not what I understand from the comments going on here. Please edit it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing command line args to MSI from WiX bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729878/passing-command-line-args-to-msi-from-wix-bundle)

Comment: ADDLOCAL is a public property; You can treat it as such even though it is a special one in that the standard Windows Installer actions read it.

Comment: @Isaiah4110 it's a dotnetInstaller

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to define a Variable within your Burn bootstrapper. Using your example, you need something like this:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
<Bundle Name="Setup" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="YOUR-GUID">

    <Variable Name="ADDLOCAL" bal:Overridable="yes"/>

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
        <MsiPackage DisplayName="Setup" Name="Setup.msi" SourceFile="Setup.msi">
            <MsiProperty Name="ADDLOCAL" Value="[ADDLOCAL]" />
        </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Now you can run `Setup.exe -q ADDLOCAL=feature` and the .msi will get that variable passed.

Answer (score 1):

Wix standard bootstrapper supports only these standard package switches->
-q, -quiet, -s, -silent = silent install
-passive = progress bar only install
-norestart = suppress any restarts
-forcerestart = restart no matter what (I don't know why this is still 
around)
-promptrestart = prompt if a restart is required (default)
-layout = create a local image of the bootstrapper (i.e. download files so 
they can be burned to DVD)
-l, -log = log to a specific file (default is controled by bundle developer) 
-uninstall = uninstall
-repair = repair (or install if not installed)
-package,-update = install (default if no -uninstall or -repair)
[Reference](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Running-Burn-driven-installer-in-quiet-mode-command-line-parameters-td5913001.html)

Comment: Thanks, -q worked. but i couldnt install a particular feature from myexe

Comment: I can install specific feature through msi using command " msiexec /i Setup.msi /qn ADDLOCAL=feature1". I want same from my setupfile.

for instance, mysetup.exe -q ADDLOCAL=feature1
Can i do that??