# How to passing checkbox values to MSI file WIX

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I've created WPF of setup file and got a checkbox to user decide show "desktop shortcut". But i got a problem to sending it to MSI File.

This is creating desktop shortcut. But I wanna add a condition in here. If WPF checkbox is checked "i wanna add it to desktop" if not nothing happens.

```
<Component Id="DesktopShortcutComponent" Guid="*">
        <RegistryValue Id="RegShortcutDesktop" Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\MyProject\1.0\settings" Name="DesktopSC" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
        <Shortcut Id="desktopSc" Target="[MYINSTALLFOLDER]\MyApplication.exe" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="MyApplication" Icon="MyProductIcon" IconIndex="0" WorkingDirectory="MYINSTALLFOLDER" Advertise="no" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveShortcutFolder" On="uninstall" />
    </Component>
```

How to passing values between custom created wpf to msi file?

Do i have to use "string values of bootstrapper"?

```
BootstrapperApplication.Engine.Plan["checkBoxValues"]
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729878/passing-command-line-args-to-msi-from-wix-bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup string or numeric variable like this

```
BootstrapperApplication.Engine.StringVariables["InstallDir"] = "somePath";
BootstrapperApplication.Engine.StringVariables["Cbx"] = "True";
BootstrapperApplication.Engine.NumericVariables["Variable"] = 1;
```

in Bundle.wxs

```
<Variable Name="InstallDir"
              bal:Overridable="yes" />
<Variable Name="Cbx"
              bal:Overridable="yes"/>


<MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.Some.Setup.TargetDir)Some.Setup.msi"
                  Id="InstallationPackageId"
                  Visible="no">
    <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallDir]" />
    <MsiProperty Name="CBX" Value="[Cbx]" />
</MsiPackage>
```

Product.wxs

```
<Property Id="CBX" Value="False" Secure="yes" />

<Component Id="Shortcut"
           Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
           Guid="68D52920-E643-42F9-B1C6-8D9D1D8C8B2E">
   <RegistryValue Id="RegShortcutDesktop"
                  Root="HKCU"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\MyProject\1.0\settings"
                  Name="DesktopSC"
                  Value="1"
                  Type="integer"
                  KeyPath="yes" />
   <Shortcut Id="desktopSc"
             Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]\Podit.exe"
             Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
             Name="Podit"
             Icon="icon.ico"
             IconIndex="0"
             WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"
             Advertise="no" />
   <Condition><![CDATA[CBX = "True"]]></Condition>
</Component>
```

Comment: How to catch this "int Variable" in Product.wxs? And check if it is 1 or 0

Comment: I wanna create desktop shortcut depends on "BootstrapperApplication.Engine.NumericVariables["Variable"] = 1" If its 1 Create shortcut on desktop, if its 0 wont create it.

Comment: @闇Yami add condition setup

Comment: `<Component Id="DesktopShortcutComponent" Guid="*">
   <RegistryValue Id="RegShortcutDesktop" Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\MyProject\1.0\settings" Name="DesktopSC" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
   <Shortcut Id="desktopSc" Target="[MYINSTALLFOLDER]\Podit.exe" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="Podit" Icon="MyProductIcon" IconIndex="0" WorkingDirectory="MYINSTALLFOLDER" Advertise="no" />
   <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveShortcutFolder" On="uninstall" />
   <Condition><![CDATA[DesktopCheckBox = 1]]></Condition>
  </Component>` why is it not working? I send 1 to this but con is not working

Comment: I checked, shortcut created fine, in `%temp%` you can find install log file, and check what value `CBX` have.

Comment: so if i wanna launch exe file after installation what should i do? i cant find any good examples is there any chance u might know?

Comment: I'm just use `Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)` from wrapped  `BootstrapperApplication` when `ApplyComplete` event fire

Comment: @闇Yami or https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092644/5446495